# Every local property for $\mathbb{R}$ (any Connected Separable Space) holds globally?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness

I'm given this problem :

> - Prove that "being polynomial" is a *local property*, meaning if $f: ℝ → ℝ$ is a polynomial in a neighborhood of each real point, then $f$ is a polynomial.

I think I have proved a more general proposition, but I need verification of my proof !

> ***Conjecture***: For any *Separable* *Connected* Topological space $(X,\tau)$, every local property $\phi(f)$ for some function $f:X\rightarrow Y$, holds entirely over $X$.

my proof :

For each $x\in X$ define $U_x$ as follows :

$\displaystyle U_x:=\bigcup_{\substack{x\in U'_x\in\tau \\ \; U'_x\text{has property}\phi}}U'_x \quad$ $\bigg($*It's the Maximal Open Set Containing $x$ $\underline{\text{with property $\phi$}}$(??)*$\bigg)$

---

***Lemma***. $\forall x,y\in X :\;U_x=U_y\;\vee\;U_x\cap U_y=\emptyset$.

**proof**. If there's $z\in X$ that $z\in U_x\cap U_y$, then since $z\in U_x\in\tau$, so $U_x\subseteq U_z$.

Since $U_z$ is a suitable open set containing $x$ and $U_x$ is maximal, therefore $U_z\subseteq U_x$. $\quad\triangledown$

---

***Corollary.*** $\{U_x\}_{x\in X}$ is a partition for $X$.

---

Let $A$ be the *countable dense* subset of $X$. Then by *Axiom of Choice*, there exists the sequence $\{q_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq A$, such that 
$\{U_{q_n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a **disjoint partition** for $X$.

---

***Claim.*** $\forall n:\; U_{q_n}=X$.

**proof.** Suppose $U_{q_n}\subsetneqq X$. Since $X$ is *connected*, $U_{q_n}\subsetneqq\overline{U_{q_n}}$. Let $y\in\overline{U_{q_n}}\setminus U_{q_n}$. Then there exists $m$ such that $y\in U_{q_m}$.

Now as $y$ is an interior point of $U_{q_m}$, so there is an open subset of $U_{q_m}$ around $y$. BUT each neighborhood of $y$ has *nonempty* intersection with $U_{q_n}$. Hence $U_{q_n}\bigcap U_{q_m}\neq\emptyset.\quad$($\bot$)

---

> ***Theorem.*** Above *conjecture* is TRUE !????

Comment: What you are getting very close to is the notion of a [sheaf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_%28mathematics%29). And if you look at the definition of a sheaf, you see that what you are essentially missing in your construction is the "gluing property" of local sections. In your case this would be something like "if property $\phi$ holds on $U_1$ and $U_2$, it holds on their union $U_1 \cup U_2$. This gluing property is basically the key of what allows you to extend from local to global.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling there is some rigor missing in your definition of property. There are certainly "properties" which hold locally (for every sufficiently small neighborhood of $x$ but not globally. A very easy example is being bounded. I.e. $\phi(f) \iff \exists m,n\in \mathbb{R}\;\forall x (n<f(x)<m)$. For every $x$ there exists a neighborhood such that $\phi(f)$ holds for $f(x)=x$. But obviously $\phi(f)$ does not hold on $\mathbb{R}$.

You might be able to fix this if you maybe require $\phi(x)$ has no existential quantifiers or something similar. But maybe I'm misunderstanding something. This particular counter example can also be fixed by also requiring your space to be compact.

Edit: One last thought on your proof. You can see where it breaks down for the counterexample I gave. There is no maximal open set for which $\phi(f)$ holds.

Comment: thanks. yes. $\phi$ must be glue-able in the context of @user225318 in the comment.

Comment: @FardadPouran Yes looking at it through the prism of sheaves is an interesting idea but gluability won't quite get you there without compactness either, being bounded is gluable: if $f(x)$ is bounded on $U_1$ and $U_2$ then it's certainly bounded on $U_1\cup U_2$. You just take maxes and mins of the bounds. But you still don't get global boundedness.

Comment: Everything depends on the nature of $\phi$. It's a good idea to categorize the properties in such way that each property needs which consumptions

Answer (score 2):

The problem of your proof is that you've never shown that $U_x$ has property $\phi$. (It is just a union of open sets which has property $\phi$). So even if you showed $U_{q_n} = X$, you still do not know whether property $\phi$ holds on $U_{q_n}$ (Hence $X$).

Your assertion is indeed false. Take $X = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$ and $\phi$ be a property on open subsets of $X$ given by

"$f$ has property $\phi$ on $U$ if $f : U \to \mathbb S^1$ is homotopic to a constant map"

Then consider $f :  X \to \mathbb S^1$, $f(r, \theta) = \theta$. Then $f$ has property $\phi$ locally for all $x\in X$, but $f$ does not have property $\phi$ on $X$.

Comment: Can for some properties $\phi$ my assertion be correct ? For example, $U_x$ has the first property I stated (continuity), am I right ?

Comment: Yes, there is true if $\phi$ is "continuity", "differentiability"...... @FardadPouran

Comment: I was wrong in the 1st comment ! Continuity was not the property I stated in the context, but it was *being polynomial* that I stated :D

Comment: Indeed, It was the special property of polynomials that "If they're equal on infnite points, they're same". Therefore All polynomials in the neighborhoods of $x$ are same, right ?